# Use of revocation certificate as id.rev

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Good afternoon everyone,

I ended up losing my passphrase to access my GPG key, but because I used the most current version when creating it, an ID.rev recall file was generated in the openpgp-revocs.d folder
When researching how to revoke the key, I saw that an .asc file is used (which I cannot generate as I no longer have the key's passphrase).
So I would like to know how I go about turning this .rev file into an .asc file to send to the server and revoke my key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The revocation certificate is ready for use as is. All that you need to do is open the `ID.rev` file in any text editor and delete the colon (`:`) at the start of the line that reads:

`:-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`

Now save the changes made to the .rev file and import it to gnupg.

`gpg --import ~/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/ID.rev`

This marks that key as revoked in your keyring. Now upload the now-revoked key to an SKS keyserver:

`gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys ID`

**Note: replace 'ID' in the above commands with the actual key ID.**